# Connect an android studio proyect to another firebase account

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, move, transfer

I have an android app in android studio that is connected to my personal firebase account. Now i need to move, transfer or connect it to another firebase account, that is a client's property. How can i do it please?

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the google-services.json.

1. Delete your personal google-service.json from the android project
2. Delete the project from the firebase console as well if you want to keep the same package name.
3. Create a new Firebase project using client account and add updated google-service.json in android project.